# How to change toolbar button item title color using Swift

Tags: swift, colors, toolbar, title

We were changing toolbar button item title color at Obj-C using

```
    [_anyToolbarButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor lightGrayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But I am unable to change when working with Swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it this way in swift:

```
_anyToolbarButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor()], forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: That works, I should have asked before, what a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
toolbar.tintColor = UIColor.red
```